# SQL Server 2008 Analysis services

Tags: sql-server, olap

I am creating an analysis dashboard using DUNDAS dashboard. For that I have to create an OLAP cube.

Is OLAP servcices already installed with SQL server 2008 or do we have to install it separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the installation, you have to choose which SQL Server component do you want to install.

You can check the documentation http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917552.aspx
and follow `Setup Options`

Comment: Is this same for SQL server 2008, because the documentation is for SQL Server 7.0

Comment: Yes in 2008, you just have to select Analysis Services in the Setup Options. 
But Olap services are not in the SQL Server Express Version.